# setAlpha not working on ViewGroup instance

Tags: android, alpha, layout-inflater, viewgroup, android-api-levels

[`setAlpha`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) has no effect on `ViewGroup` instances in API levels 14(ICS)-19(KitKat) even though it was introduced in API level 11. Any ideas why?

I've even tried using the support library but that doesn't work either.

Example:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
view.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

It works perfectly fine for API levels 21+ but not for API levels 14-19.

PS, I haven't tested below API level 14.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Find any solution?

Comment: No, it may be a bug in older android versions.

Comment: Got the same problem atm...

Comment: @Denny If you find a solution, remember to post it here!

Comment: You too @NicCapdevila

Comment: @Denny Just seen some other questions regarding this problem, try this on your problem (i cant test it atm). Some people cant set the alpha of the view background on api 21+ in the same way we cant set the alpha of the view itself before api 21. So just a hunch, try and set the alpha of the background for api levels before 21+, see if that works. And let me know if it does!

Comment: @sudoman Nope doesn't work =[

Comment: @Denny thanks for trying